# Destructuring Object in JS - Nested Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, destructuring

How can I handle destructuring a nested object that might have an undefined internal object?

For example.

I have a xhr req that returns `{person: user: {}}`

For example: `const xhrResponse = {person: user: 'hi'}}`

I am only interested in the user portion so I destruct.

`const {person: {user}} = xhrResponse`

`console.log(user) => 'hi'`

However what if the api returns `{person: null}`

My destructuring fails with `Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'.`

I have a solution but I feel like there might be a more elegant solution.

*Solution*

`const handleResponse(res) => res.person ? res : {person: user: {}}`

Is there a better way to handle this? Or even another way, the use of the word better is sometimes synonymous with opinion :D

More Complete Use Case:

```
$q.all([somePromise, someOtherPromise, getPersonPromise])
  .then(promises => [vm.promise1, vm.promise2, {person: {user: vm.user}] = promises);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you just use this?

```
const {user} = xhrResponse.person || {};
```

---

For the updated use case I wonder whether this would be viable?

```
$q.all([
  somePromise,
  someOtherPromise,
  getPersonPromise.then(res => (res.person || {}).user)
]).then(promises => [vm.promise1, vm.promise2, vm.user] = promises);
```

Comment: Could work as well but my use case I am trying to fix wont allow this. The above is a contrived example as close to my problem as possible.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the extra constraints that make this nonviable? Is the line where you do the destructuring itself unchangeable? Difficult to make suggestions without knowing what I'm allowed to change about your original solution.

Comment: Ill add the complete use case.

Comment: added a more complete picture

Comment: @StenMuchow I've updated my answer, I don't know whether it'll be any use to you but it's the best I could come up with.

Comment: hmmm... very interesting... i like. lemme try it out

Comment: awesome cleans up my nested destruct as well, not a huge fan of that.

Comment: @StenMuchow @skirtle, you can't assume that `xhrResponse` will always be an object. This is error prone, what if  `xhrResponse` for any reason is `undefined` or `null` this will crash!

Comment: @JoseAPL If that is a genuine concern you can use exactly the same trick to defend against it. That said, you've got to trust your APIs to stick to their contracts and there was nothing in the OP's question to suggest that that particular object could be `null` or `undefined`. In this context I would imagine that `getPersonPromise` would be rejected if the response were not available for any reason.

Comment: @skirtle there are many different factors that can easily break your contact. 
 network connections, server accessibility, server timeout, unavailable server, etc. For this reason, you have to safely trust your contract, coding well!

Answer (score 2):

You can add default values for nested stuff as well:

```
const handleResponse = ({ person: { user = {}} = {}} = {}) => {
  console.log(user);
}

handleResponse({});
```

(i'm assuming you using es6 based on your arrow functions)

edit: sry, only works with undefined values, but not if a value is null 
will leave the answer in here anyway as it might be useful to other readers

Comment: So we cant do this assignment of default values without the handleResponse method?

Comment: no, works with all object deconstructions like `const { person: { user = {}} = {}} = {};
console.log(user);`

Comment: "(i'm assuming you using es6 based on your arrow functions)" - yeah also since we are using destructuring ;)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like to see clearly the parameters my function is receiving.

I will go with this solution:

```
const handleResponse = (response) => {
  const { person: { user } = {} } = response || {};

  // since user is the value to be used you don't need to set a default unless you need it
  if (user) // do your stuff here
}
```

Doing tedious destructuring can end in unreadable code

**So doing progressive destructuring, feels like a better solution to me.**

Comment: Pretty sure this is gonna throw the same error. Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'.